# Highcharts Gantt milestone series

Tags: highcharts

I'm new to Highcharts and have been experimenting with the Gantt chart type, unfortunately there isnt a whole heap of documentation around right now.

My requirement is quite basic, I need to plot multiple series of milestones in order to show slippage of different projects. I've used some example code I found online to start me off however I need to remove the blank ('My 1st Row') line between the series. see:-

https://jsfiddle.net/z86aq99g

```
    var today = new Date(),
    day = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;

    var grey_OrigTargDate = '#A6A6A6';
    var blue_Completed = '#2e75b6';
    var green_Ontarget = '#00b050';
    var yellow_OfftrackMinor = '#ffc000';
    var red_OffTrackMajor = '#ff0000';

// Set to 00:00:00:000 today
today.setUTCHours(0);
today.setUTCMinutes(0);
today.setUTCSeconds(0);
today.setUTCMilliseconds(0);
today = today.getTime();

// THE CHART

Highcharts.setOptions({
    colors: ['#058DC7']
});

Highcharts.ganttChart('container', {
    title: {
        text: 'Gantt Chart Test'
    },
    xAxis: {
        currentDateIndicator: true,
        min: today - 3 * day,
        max: today + 18 * day
    },

    series: [{
        name: 'Test series',
        data: [{
            taskName: 'My 1st row',
            id: 'r1',
            start: today + 4.5 * day,
            milestone: true,
            color: grey_OrigTargDate
        }, {
            taskName: 'My 1st row',
            id: 'r2',
            start: today + 7.5 * day,
            milestone: true,
            color: green_Ontarget
        }, {
            taskName: 'My 2nd row',
            id: 'r3',
            start: today + 9.5 * day,
            milestone: true,
            color: blue_Completed
        }, {
            taskName: 'My 2nd row',
            id: 'r4',
            start: today + 11.5 * day,
            milestone: true,
            color: red_OffTrackMajor
        }]
    }]
});
```

I am trying to chart 2 milestones on each line. I know that the x range series chart *could* accomplish something similar but I'd much prefer to use the gantt option. I'd appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2):

You can solve this problem by assigning categories to the `Y-axis`

```
 yAxis: {
    type: 'category',
    categories: ['A', 'B'],
    reversed: true,        
 },
```

In order for this to work you could change the `taskName` with `y: 0` / `y: 1`. It will work if your `taskName` is identical to your category names, but using `y: 0` is more dynamic if you were to change the categories.

Your code will look like this in the end:

```
 var today = new Date(),
    day = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;

    var grey_OrigTargDate = '#A6A6A6';
    var blue_Completed = '#2e75b6';
    var green_Ontarget = '#00b050';
    var yellow_OfftrackMinor = '#ffc000';
    var red_OffTrackMajor = '#ff0000';

// Set to 00:00:00:000 today
today.setUTCHours(0);
today.setUTCMinutes(0);
today.setUTCSeconds(0);
today.setUTCMilliseconds(0);
today = today.getTime();

// THE CHART

Highcharts.setOptions({
    colors: ['#058DC7']
});

Highcharts.ganttChart('container', {
    title: {
        text: 'Gantt Chart Test'
    },
    xAxis: {
        currentDateIndicator: true,
        min: today - 3 * day,
        max: today + 18 * day
    },

    yAxis: {
        type: 'category',
        categories: ['A', 'B'],
        reversed: true,

    },

    series: [{
        name: 'Test series',
        data: [{
            y: 0, // taskName: 'A' works too
            id: 'r1',
            start: today + 4.5 * day,
            milestone: true,
            color: grey_OrigTargDate
        }, {
            y: 0,
            id: 'r2',
            start: today + 7.5 * day,
            milestone: true,
            color: green_Ontarget
        },{
            y: 1,
            id: 'r3',
            start: today + 9.5 * day,
            milestone: true,
            color: blue_Completed
        }, {
            y: 1,
            id: 'r4',
            start: today + 11.5 * day,
            milestone: true,
            color: red_OffTrackMajor
        }]
    }]
});
```

Here is a working JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/z86aq99g/1/

Comment: There's a [thread on the official Highcharts forum](https://www.highcharts.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=19&t=44894) that gives an example of how to do this by setting `yAxis: { uniqueNames: true } }`, but that then requires you to name all the milestone points you want on the same line to have the same name.  This is so much better because each milestone can keep it's true name, so you don't have to mess as much with overriding the tooltips and adding custom properties etc in order to show the correct names.